# How do I change Magento search to bring up products no matter what order the search terms are in?

Tags: search

I have a problem with **Magento search**. The search terms have to be in the exact order the way they are listed in the **title**.

Example: If I search for **"Big Green Truck"** I get product results but if I search for **"Green Big Truck"** nothing comes up. There has to be an easy code fix for this. Please help, I am a new-bee

Thank you

Comment: Try changing the search mode to "Fulltext & Like". You can do that from system->configuration->catalog.

Answer (score -1):

/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php

At line 345 change OR to AND

Please let me know if its ok. Tks

Edit: dont forget to delete existing search terms and refresh cache

Answer (score -3):

Magento internal search is 20-50% accurate, SPhinx/Lucene 60-80% accurate, Solr is 98% accurate - so we use solr. You can fiddle with the sql but in the end you are limited by the fundamentatls of sql search.

Comment: What a proposterly incorrect answer. SOLR is Lucene! Not to mention no search engine has a percentage rating for accuracy. It is as accurate as you make it.